# How can I validate a String HH:MM:SS against the upload time displayed in a table using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I couldn't implement the below scenario using Selenium Java.

I captured the current system time to a **StringABC**. Now the String is like *HH:MM:SS*.

In the next step I uploaded a file and then redirected to a page that contains a table showing the time stamp of file Upload which is in the format *DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS*.

My problem is, I want to check whether the file upload time stamp contains the value I stored in the **StringABC**

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check that datetime value contains time value, you can just use `string1.contains(string2)`.

About full date time comparison - consider html like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>

<span>2022-06-23 15:01:02</span>
<input type="text" value="2022-06-23 23:59:59">

</body>
</html>
```

Code example:

```
package tests;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import selenium.ChromeDriverSetup;

public class Anandhu extends ChromeDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver(); // wrapped driver init
        driver.get("file:///C:/foo.html");
        
        LocalDateTime myDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2022, Month.JUNE, 23, 15, 1, 2);
        WebElement span = driver.findElement(By.tagName("span"));
        String spanText = span.getText();
        LocalDateTime spanLocalDateTime = getLocalDateTimeFromStringOfPattern(spanText, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("spanLocalDateTime equals myDateTime: " + spanLocalDateTime.equals(myDateTime));
        
        WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
        String inputValue = input.getAttribute("value");
        LocalDateTime inputLocalDateTime = getLocalDateTimeFromStringOfPattern(inputValue, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("inputLocalDateTime equals myDateTime: " + inputLocalDateTime.equals(myDateTime));

        driver.quit();
    }
    
    public static String getStringFromLocalDateTimeOfPattern(LocalDateTime ldt, String pattern) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        return ldt.format(dateTimeFormatter);
    }
    
    public static LocalDateTime getLocalDateTimeFromStringOfPattern(String string, String pattern) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        return LocalDateTime.parse(string, formatter);  
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819}) on port 26628
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Čer 23, 2022 3:18:51 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
spanLocalDateTime equals myDateTime: true
inputLocalDateTime equals myDateTime: false
```